# Cordova Media Plugin Query

Tags: java, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I have one question I am using cordova media plugin for playing background music for my app after 15 or 14 repeatation sound of audio file get pause or mute nothing to get any sound please help me out on it

Comment: code please...?

Comment: $scope.mediaAudio = $cordovaMedia.newMedia($scope.audioFile);
 $scope.mediaAudio.play();